# tkinter: stacking Buttons on top of eachother

Tags: python, tkinter

So in a frame I created a simple button (button1). This does nothing but the important part is that I created button2 which is placed on button1. The buttons function normally. For example I can click button2 to forget button1 which makes button2 automatically disappear since it is placed in button1 and that's exactly what I want. But I get this wierd bug where button2 is sometimes visible and sometimes isn't. You have to move your mouse around and sometimes it appears and is clickable and it will sometimes disappear if you move your mouse away. It also disappears when you click button1. But I want it to be visible at all times. Sort of like button2 would have a priority over button1. How can I fix this wierd bug?

```
from tkinter import *

def delete_buttons():
    button1.place_forget()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

frame = Frame(root, bg="yellow")
frame.place(relx = 0.1, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8)

# button 2 is created on top of button1
button1 = Button(frame, text="this is a button")
button1.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.2, relwidth=0.6, relheight=0.6)
button2 = Button(button1, text="delete 1st and 2nd button", command=delete_buttons)
button2.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.6, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.3)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably buttons are not intended to be used as a parent widget, so unexpected behavior can arise.

You could use the `frame` as parent for both buttons and still display them on top of each other. You will just need to calculate the position more carefully, as it is now relative to the frame and not to `button1`.

```
# change the delete function to:
def delete_buttons():
    button1.place_forget()
    button2.place_forget()

# and button2 to:
button2 = Button(frame, text="delete 1st and 2nd button", command=delete_buttons)
button2.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.55, relwidth=0.4, relheight=0.2)
```

Comment: Okay thanks. That should do it. Is button2 on top of button1 because it was written/placed later?

Comment: @EnriqueMetner yes.